# Restore for SOLR standalone server is failing with IndexNotFoundException

Tags: solr, solr4, sunspot-solr

I have SOLR running on a standalone server, i was testing for backup and restore in order to take the backup I have used below command

`curl  'http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/replication?command=backup'`

The above command is able to take the backup successfully.  But i used below command to restore the previously  taken backup.

`curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/replication?command=restore'`

Which used the latest available backup and restored successfully.  But i wanted to pass the backup name in the command, So i tried the below command

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/replication?command=restore&name=snapshot.2017xxxxxx'`
```

when i ran this the backup didn't go well am getting a error as below when checked the restore status

```
<str name="status">failed</str><str name="exception">org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in MMapDirectory@/database/solr/data/UMB/data/snapshot.snapshot.20170503060914378 lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@9ee14c9: files: []</str></lst>
```

Could anyone please suggest me whats going wrong. The SOLR is hosted on Cent OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found out what was causing the issues. for SOLR hosted on linux when we pass the backup name instead of passing complete name like snapshot.2017xxxxx we just need to exclude the snapshot and pass only the timestamp details. the command would be something like below

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/UMB/replication?command=restore&name=2017xxxxxxxxx'
```